# Possible to use runAs in Apex Trigger?

Tags: apex, trigger

Is it possible to use `system.runAs()` methods in a trigger? If it possible please provide sample code.

Comment: no not possible. `system.RunAs()` methods  only available in test class.

Comment: Perhaps you can invoke a utility class and use the `with sharing` keyword to enforce the user sharing rules if that is your use case.

Comment: What is your use case for this?

Answer (score 5):

This method can only be used in tests. You can find the documentation for `System.runAs` [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.198.0.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_system.htm#apex_System_System_runAs_2). Its documentation says:

> All of the specified user's record sharing is enforced during the execution of runAs. You can only use runAs in a test method. For more information, see [Using the runAs Method](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.198.0.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_tools_runas.htm).

Answer (score 5):

Short answer: no.

Longer answer: The System.runAs block was designed to support unit testing, and as such, is only allowed in a unit test context. If you're trying to impersonate another user, you would have to somehow "log in" as them and perform whatever you're doing by way of an API call. This, in turn, suggests you'd need to, at minimum, use a @future, Queueable, Schedulable, or Batchable method/class, call the API to log in as that user (I'd suggest REST here, but any of the APIs that provide a login method would be suitable), then perform whatever it is you're trying to do using that newly created session ID. This entire process is fairly trivial, but completely not obvious, and would take some initial investment in research to get it right.

Comment: This is a good outline of the technical implementation, but seems to carry huge risk. I'm curious what kind of steps you might take to mitigate that?

Comment: @AdrianLarson Personally, I'd use OAuth2-- make the user to be impersonated login and store their refresh token and auth token in a custom setting, encrypted, of course. This way the user being impersonated could terminate the session at any time, and their username nor password is ever exposed directly. Admins would still be able to recover the data, but normal users wouldn't know how to get at the data (or even have the permissions needed to write the necessary code).

Answer (score 2):

Alternate approach:

- Create a Platform Event `Delegated_Work__e`
- Configure it [so the running user is some userXXX](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.230.0.platform_events.meta/platform_events/platform_events_trigger_config.htm) (by default, it will run as `Automated Process` user
- Subscribe to the Platform Event using a trigger
- Code the trigger to do the work
- Publish the Platform Event when needed `EventBus.publish(new Delegated_Work__c());`