# Delete records as user NOT in test

Tags: apex, user, runas

Is there a way to programatically delete records as a certain user? RunAs() is only for tests, but for normal Apex classes?

There may be an answer here [Alternatives to run as](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/104881/possible-to-use-runas-in-apex-trigger), but logging in as the user is far too complex for a simple piece of code.

Alternatively, is there a way to set a link to a certain record in a recycle bin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest approach would generally be:

1. Set up a shadow object to request deletion (with a lookup to the record to delete)
2. Set up a schedulable batch that loops over those records and performs the deletion
3. Have the user you want to perform the deletion schedule that job
4. When you would want to delete the records as someone else, insert the shadow request records instead

Comment: Thanks, Adrian, for your swift response. I do not understand parts of it yet, though. Why would I want to set up that shadow object? And why would I want to "insert the shadow request records" and not delete it?

Comment: Because the scheduled job will always run in the context of that user. So if you want that user to do the deletion, you have them batch over the shadow records and execute the requests.

Answer (score 0):

Alternate approach:

- Create a Platform Event `Delegated_Delete__e`
- Configure it [so the running user is some userXXX](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_messaging_trigger_config.htm&type=5&release=230) (by default, it will run as `Automated Process` user
- Subscribe to the Platform Event using a trigger
- Code the trigger to do the work
- Publish the Platform Event when needed `EventBus.publish(new Delegated_Delete__c());`